# How to notify other components of GraphQL mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

Let's imagine I'm developing a simple todo app, and in terms of react components it's structured like this (*not actual react code*)

```
<AddTodo />
<TodoList>
  <TodoItem ..>
  <TodoItem ..>
</TodoList>
```

`TodoList` component is wrapped in `graphql(gql '..some query')` HOC, and also into `graphql(qql'..some mutation')` to handle querying of todo items and toggling their `done` state; When a mutation is invoked `TodoList` component knows to rerender itself with fresh data.

`AddTodo` is wrapped with another HOC adding another mutation to add new todo item. However triggering it doesn't re-render `TodoList`.

This little app doesn't have any state management like redux, my understanding is that React-Apollo is meant to replace redux. Why does refresh happen automatically in `TodoList` and how to propagate refresh from `AddTodo` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to notify `TodoList` that a new Todo is added

1. Update your cache store after you do mutation by `update` option. Example:

   ```
   ...
   this.props.addTodo({
    variables: {
     content: text,
    },
    update: (store, { data: { addTodo } }) => {
     const data = store.readQuery({query: your_query_name})
     // do update store here ...
     store.writeQuery({query: your_query_name, data})
    }
   })
   ...
   ```
2. Use `Subscription` and `subscribeToMore` option follow the instruction [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-subscriptions/)

Comment: it appears to me that this approach does not promote separation of concerns, and queries, mutations and updates are scattered throughout the code. Unlike with redux where best practice is to only `connect()` top level components.

Comment: I agree with you, the approach 1 is the same with redux, use `cache` instead of `redux` store. You should use it in case don't need response from server like you add new todo and only you can see it. And the approach 2 might be useful incase you add new todo and others can see it, it'll notify to all `subscriber`